# Dynamically wire OSGi Services by configuration properties

Tags: java, osgi, bndtools

I am currently facing a problem of how to dynamically "wire" OSGi Services depending on their configuration properties. I want to do that with Declarative Services.

To give a concrete example:
I have two different OSGi Services A and B which both are ManagedServiceFactories and require configuration. So I can have multiple instances of A and multiple instances of B each with separate configurations.

I use Felix FileInstall, DS/SCR and BNDTools and my configs look like this (simplified):

**a-one.cfg:**
b.id = foo

**a-two.cfg:**
b.id = bar

**b-one.cfg:**
id = foo

**b-two.cfg:**
id = bar

Now I want to wire/bind service b-one to a-one and service b-two to a-two (depending on their matching configuration properties b.id = id).

Currently I can see two approaches on how to achieve this:

1. Bind **all** available instances of Service B to the instances of Service A and select the proper Service B depending on its id.
2. Implement an own ManagedServiceFactory for Service A which creates an LDAP filter to find the proper instance of Service B.

For solution 1.) I do not like that I need to bind all instances of Service B to every instance of Service A. I like to only bind the instance of Service B which meets my configuration property constraint.

For solution 2.) I do not like that I need to dig to the lower levels: own ManagedServiceFactory and bypassing DS by manually find the proper (LDAP filtered) Service instance.

Do anyone know a better solution or "best practice" how to achieve that?
I am not sure if maybe the WireAdmin spec can help me here?

Solution with BNDTools/BND Annotation would be welcomed ;)

tia

Cheers
Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DS always puts all configuration information as service properties if it registers a service for a Component. You should do the same in your A and B ManagedServiceFactory so the services will be searchable.

On the other hand, if you specify a property for your reference with the ".target" suffix, you can specify via configuration which service to pick up.

With your example:

- You create a component for *B*
- You specify a reference in component *B* for services *A* with the name *a*
- You specify a property in component *B* with the name *a.target*
- You configure *a.target* with LDAP search filters. If you do not specify a value for this property, a random *A* service will be picked up

Comment: Hi Balazs, thx very much your your detailed answer. Thats EXACTLY what I searched for. I knew this must be a common use case and there must be a better and more easy solution than the two I listed above. I just set up a POC project with two components and you are right: "a.target = (id=one)" did the trick. I did not know about this ".target" extension (without knowing that a Google search for that is hard ;) ). Fascinated how easy it can be with OSGi....it's just mind-blowing ;)

Comment: If anyone has trouble getting this to work I shared my POC (which makes use of BND Annotations) here: https://github.com/shomeier/bnd_poc